# Prevent duplicate request by the email in .NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading

I have an `API Action` that handle `POST` requests. What I need to do is to prevent  duplicate handling for the same email until the first process is over. I see two ways to do this:

1. Make an `SQL Transaction` that check the table and if not exists insert and return `false` or `true` otherwise. Then we will remove record from the table when transaction is over. I don't like it because if, let's say, IIS will be restarted during the process table will have the record and we need to find way to handle it.
2. Make `ConcurrentDictionary` so we can check if the record exists then decline duplicate request. The code I made using C# `ConcurrentDictionary<string, string>`:

---

```
if (!Singleton.TransactionEmails.TryAdd(email, email))
    // decline        
try
{
    // transaction logic here
}
catch(Exception ex)
{ 
    // catch logic here 
}
finally 
{ 
    string pendingEmail = string.Empty;    
    Singleton.TransactionEmails.TryRemove(email, out pendingEmail);
}
```

---

I have several questions. Do you see any advantage of using the first way? My code doesn't look like thread safe. Do I need to use `lock` and where I need it? Does exist more efficient way to prevent duplicate transactions without locking table or threads?

Comment: if this API is based on a stateless request/response model, your concurrent dictionary would have to be stored in an ASP.NET data structure that survives between requests. is that the case? `ConcurrentDictionary` is inherently threadsafe, that's its whole purpose. I think the real question here is *how do we detect a duplicate e-mail?* (define a suitable equalitycomparer for example) and *where do we prevent duplicates?* (I would do this using a hash, and one of the generic `IDictionary` implementations of the framework, on `Add`, simply ignoring subsequent attempts to add on hash collision.

Comment: (going to SQL server to use its transactional capabilities just for this is unecessary, but if you have SQL server in the project anyway, it may be worth logging the mails you sent, so you can at the same time implement your mail queue and enforce unique mails there).

Comment: @dlatikay The dictionary now is a part of the singleton, so it survives between requests. What I asking is can be the situation when, let's say, two request threads  
 try to add same email into the dictionary and 'else' statement will be ignored.

Comment: yes, a race condition. I suggest to rethink the approach and use `TryAdd` only. it will [reliably return false](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentdictionary-2.tryadd?view=netframework-4.7.2) if the element already existed.

Comment: @dlatikay I edited the question. Could you please review now?

Comment: Better question is why would your api call to send the email twice, what are you sending a confirmation email, explain the problem a bit more?

Comment: @johnny5 unfortunately, it doesn't depend on me. I tried to ask why it happens, but didn't get the answer. So I just try to prevent handling.

Comment: Ideally you should have a service which handles this, which you can just queue items to

Comment: @johnny 5, it happens occasionally. That is what guys who use API told me. They don't know the reason told that will try to find the problem maybe later. I don't want to wait them and I don't need queue for that call but I agree in general.

Comment: You don’t need a queue but if you had one you could filter out duplicates

Answer (score 0):

First seems betther to me. Because everytime IIS restarts your web application, your dictionary from your second method will be empty and accepts duplicates. The problem you mentioned in first method actually belongs to second method.

Comment: if IIS restarts then server can't handle requests